# How to show closing tag in folded code in javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

In my html file I can see the closing tag of folded code:

[image: open tags html]

[image: closed tags html]

But it is not visible in my js files (jsx syntax):

[image: open tags js]

[image: closed tags js]

I'm sorry if this is a silly question. But i hope someone can help me to have it shown as well in js files.

Comment: You need to move your code from images to stack overflow markdown

Comment: @MikeMalyi, he is not asking about the code but trying to visualize the behavior of his IDE. Moving the code to stack overflow markdown won't help here.

To everyone who is downvoting this, at least explain why you are downvoting.

Comment: Agree with henk here. This is a valid question in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your settings.json file:

```
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
```